# Magento2 Shipping Table rates show 0€

Tags: magento2, shipping, table-rates

We have a problem with shipping costs, randomly not working and show 0€ (some products works and others not, all created in the exactly same way)

For Shipping Methods our Magento is configured with  Table Rates, and all other methods are disabled.
This is the "Tables rates" configuration:

```
Enabled:"Yes"
Title:"Shipping costs by weight"
Method Name: "shipping price"
Condition:"Weight Vs. Destination"
Include Virtual Products in Price Calculation: "No"
Calculate Handling Fee: "Fixed"
Handling Fee: 0
Displayed Error Message. "Error"
Ship to Applicable Countries: "Speciific Countries"
Ship to Specific Countries: "Spain"
Show Method if Not Applicable: "No"
Sort Order: 1
```

I have this CSV

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Weight (and above)","Shipping Price"
*,*,*,0.0000,8.5000
*,*,*,25.0000,5.5000
*,*,*,50.0000,1.0000
```

Also for the country we have tried to put the code "ES" and "ESP".

We experience the problem with all types of products: configurable, simple, grouped.
and in all products we have put the weight.
We tried to update magento from version 2.0.5 to 2.0.7
We tried to downgrade the PHP7 to PHP5.6,
Constantly we tried switch between production mode and developer mode.
also we tried compile, clear the cache ... without result.

Our current configuration:

```
PHP 7.0.2
Nginx 1.10.0
Magento 2.0.7
Dedicat hosting
```

Someone has been the same probleme.
Can you help us please

Thanks in advance!.